# How to manage page performance and initial video size on a page with a lot of videos

Tags: css, video

I have a lot of videos on page, like this:

```
<video class='avid' controls preload='none' poster ='...'><source src='...' type='video/mp4'></video>
```

videos are inside a vertical column - `parent` div
some videos are horizontal, some vertical - so various dimensions

**css**

```
.parent{width:720px;}

.avid{
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

In order to keep page performances I need `preload='none'`
But in that case - initial video width is 480px
After clicking on play button - a video resizes itself - and that's a very ugly user experience

Is there a way to keep page performances and get a normal initial video width ?

Comment: Add `width: 100%` perhaps? Just because you specified a `max-width:100%`, doesn't give the element any incentive to grow in width, if it has _less_ than the parent's width.

Comment: @CBroe - in that case problem is with videos having natural width of let's say - 540px

Comment: Make it a min-width then?

Comment: @CBroe - this will affect  video resolution if the video natural width i below min-width